# OECD API access unable to find dataset identifiers

Tags: api, oecd

I'm trying to access OECD data through their API

The [documentation](https://data.oecd.org/api/sdmx-json-documentation/) says the query string should look like this:

```
http://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/data/<dataset identifier>/<filter expression>/<agency name>
```

with a working example being:

```
http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/QNA/all/all
```

I'd like to change the `<dataset identifier>` to point to different datasets, but I can't find the Ids used. The documentation states:

> Available datasets are listed in the [catalogue of OECD databases](https://data.oecd.org/searchresults/?hf=20&b=0&r=f/type/datasets/api%20access&l=en) with
> API. Queries can be built using the **Export / Developer API feature** of
> the dataset browser.

But the catalogue doesn't appear to have an `Export / Developer API feature`. how can I find the correct API strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the XML description here:

https://stats.oecd.org/RestSDMX/sdmx.ashx/GetKeyFamily/all

After digging through this R package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OECD/OECD.pdf